# How to use a query to find a row of same name but last entry, then copy a value next to it (update request)

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

(This is an updated version of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151199/how-to-use-a-query-to-find-a-row-of-same-name-but-last-entry-then-copy-a-value) - I am trying my best to make myself clearer this time.)

I am trying to use a query to copy values from one column to another.

**Both source and destination columns have a name on their left columns**, and the name must match. The source names could be duplicated, and in that case, I would like to have the entry on the bottom. There could be empty rows as well.

If a name in the source is not found in the destination, then don't copy it.

If a name in the destination is not found in the source, then leave the destination value blank.

Please see the picture.
[image: demo picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use
*(Do adjust ranges to your needs)*

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2:G, 
                QUERY(SORTN(SORT({ROW(D2:D),D2:E},1,0),9^9,2,2,1), 
                    " select Col2, Col3 where Col2<>'' "),2,0)))
```

[image]

**How the formula works**

We create a virtual column based on each row, sort and query the result.
We then use the `VLOOKUP` function to search the values from column `G` in the range of the query results with the help of the `Arrayformula`

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ROW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316)
- [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.